# What is the professional way to combat duplication of classes used in multiple projects?

Tags: ios

Here's a common scenario: I have 5 apps, and a lot of common categories or helper classes. Every time I create a new app, I copy-paste the helper classes and categories from my previous app.

Then I end up with multiple Xcode projects and each has duplicate of my helper classes.

Then one day Apple comes and introduces iOS 7. Hey, this deprecated. That deprecated. This doesn't work. That also doesn't work. So I go in and fix the problems in my helper classes. And then I copy-paste my changes over to all my other projects as well. It takes me 10 hours and 30% heart attack.

So I start to think about improving this "workflow".

As I am new to programming the question is how do the professionals do it. How do they deal with common classes and files that they use across all apps.

Here is what I think but I suppose you have a better idea:

1) Create a folder somewhere. Call it "CommonTools" maybe.

2) Move all common "shared" files from the latest project to this folder.

3) Then remove ALL duplicates from ALL projects.

4) Then drag-drop all the files from CommonTools folder into each project as required. But "add reference" only, NOT copy to project directory. So it is only file ref.

Then when you edit ONE of the common files, change applies to ALL projects.

But I have seen some crazy big open source projects which have a lot of sub xcode projects in them. I am afraid my folder idea is stupid. Can someone explain the good way?

Comment: Is this question better suited to programmers than here?

Comment: @ProudMember Programmers is a different site on stackexchange, he's saying it maybe would've been better suited for there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:  Use Static Libraries

A static library involves making a package of classes, which you can use in as many projects as you want.

[Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial)

---

Option 2:  Use source control

If all of your projects are under source control, you could just make the changes you need once, then grab the latest version of these files in all of your Xcode projects.

Since you're using XCode, you should check out the support for Git:  [Ray Wenderlich Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6)

Comment: And how about you drag in a different xcode project into an xcode project? i often see embedded projects.

Comment: @ProudMember that might work I am not sure.  Why don't you just try it?